# Exterior, Interior, Boundary

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> If we denote the general point of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $(x,y)$, determine $\operatorname{Int}A$, $\operatorname{Ext}A$, and $\operatorname{Bd}A$ for the subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ specified by each of the following conditions
>
> (a) $x = 0$
>
> (b) $0 \leq x < 1$

For (a), could $\operatorname{Bd}A= \varnothing$? Because I can't decide whether $x = 0$ is open or closed. I have that $\operatorname{Int}A= A$

I am also having trouble writing my $\operatorname{Ext}A$ in a compact way. The following is what I have

$$\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:-\infty < x < 0\} \cup \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:0 < x < \infty\} $$

How do I write this more compactly? Perhaps using cross product?

(b) For $\operatorname{Ext}A$, same problem. I had to write it as a union of two disjoint sets. For $\operatorname{Int}A$, is it okay to just leave as $\operatorname{Int}A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: 0 < x < 1\}$? Can I assume that the reader knows $-\infty < y < \infty$?

Comment: For a , I think we should consider $A=\{(x,y)\mid x,y\in\mathbb R, x=0\}$ instead. Shouldn't we??

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean $x=0$ should epitomize a subset in $\mathbb R^2$. What $x=0$ mean in the Cartesian plane?

Comment: Are you asking me what $x = 0$ it is in $\mathbb{R}^2$? It's the y-axis

Comment: I know that. ;-) I am remarking you the notation you used for the set $A$. That is it!. ;-)

Comment: I wrote it as $A = \{ (0, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a), the boundary is not empty. Every point in $A$ where $x=0$ is adjacent to points in $A$ and points not in $A$, informally speaking. So Bd A = $\{(x,y)~|~x=0\}$. The interior of the set is what is empty. The exterior you can write more simply $\{(x,y)~|~x\neq0\}$

Part (b) you can do the same thing in describing the exterior. Your description of the interior looks good to me and you can indeed assume $-\infty<y<\infty$ because that is inherent in the definition of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: For (a), that's what I am confused about. Why isn't the interior the same as $A$? I can certinaly draw a neighborhood in A such that it is still contained in the set no? And why do you say the boundary is 0 and not 0?

Comment: @sizz: No, you can’t: any nbhd of a point $\langle 0,y\rangle$ must contain points with non-zero $x$-coordinate.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, how? I am fixing $x = 0$, how can I escape from $A$? I don't see how the nbhd can contain other x-points

Comment: @sizz How does your text/notes define interior and boundary of a set? One way to define it (not sure if it is the one you should use in your class) is that you can draw a ball around an interior point that is completely contained in $A$, whereas any ball drawn around a boundary point, no matter how small, contains points in $A$ and points not in $A$.

Comment: Neighborhoods don't necessarily live in $A$. They live in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I use all these terms accordingly to Rudin, but right now I got this example from Munkres and he pretty much defines it the same way, *The interior of A, as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined to be the union of all open sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that contained in $A$*

Comment: @sizz: Every open set containing $\langle 0,y\rangle$ contains an open ball of positive radius centred at $\langle 0,y\rangle$; if the radius is $\epsilon$, that ball contains every point $\langle x,y\rangle$ with $-\epsilon<x<\epsilon$.

Comment: @RussH, "reads what I just wrote and your comment". Ohh, so the neighorhoods here are disks, not intervals? That's why Brain was saying it contains other points?

Comment: @sizz: Yes: you’re working in $\Bbb R^2$ with its usual topology, not just in the $y$-axis.

Comment: @RussH, for (a) Are you just saying that BdA = A? And for (b), how can I do the "same thing"? The interior is infinite rectangle, not a strip this time. I still don't see any easy way to write it without doing the union of two infinite rectangles

Comment: Oh wait you probably mean to say $Ext A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x > 1, x < 0 \}$? I don't see how this is the "same" though

Comment: yeah, i guess i could have been a little more clear. It's the 'same' in that you are combining two sets into one, but it's not really the same. I'd actually maybe say $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x>1~\mathrm{or}~x<0\}$

Comment: Just one more thing, is it acceptable to write the Bd A for (b) as $\{ (0,y) \cup (1, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\}$

Comment: i don't see anything wrong with it